# Set-PnPListItem Column '{my column name}' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

Something is wacky with my SharePoint list.  When I use `Get-PnPListItem -List $listTitle -ID $id` It returns only 3 columns: Id, Title, and GUID.  Likewise, when I try to use `Get-PnPListItem` I only have those 3 fields to choose from.  If I use `Set-PnPListItem -List $listTitle -Identity $id -Values @{"FieldName" = $value}` it tells me "Column '{my column name}' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user." but this is the syntax that is recommended by most sites.  I haven't been able to get it to work.

If I use `Get-PnPField -List $listTitle` I can actually see all the fields in my list, but when I try and use `Set-PnPField` it seems more like how to update metadata and properties of the field rather than its actual contents.

I'm pretty lost here.  How can I update my list items using PnP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some "poke and hope" I found [this discussion](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2226141-set-pnplistitem-is-not-updating-editor-field) where somebody is playing with the "UpdateType" argument that is "optional" but really shouldn't be.

This works:

`Set-PnPListItem -Identity $id -List $listTitle -Values @{"MyField"="Field Value"} -UpdateType UpdateOverwriteVersion`